# Send files through AJAX using FormData to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a simple model:

```
public class MyModel {
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public HttpPostedFileBase File {get; set; }
}
```

and my MVC action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(List<MyModel> data) {
   // do soemthing
}
```

and finally JavaScript:

```
$("#chooseFile").on("change", function (){
    var files = $(this).prop("files");
    var array = [];    

   for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj.Description = "My custom description" + i;
      obj.File = files[i];

      array.push(obj);
   }

   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("data", array);

   var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "/test/Upload");
   xmlHttpRequest.send(formData);
});
```

The problem is that `data` from the `Upload` action always has `Count = 0` . Where is my mistake ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: That won't help me... Please read question, not title.

Comment: Because I send a custom list of object, this has nothing to do with form except choosing file from local computer.

Comment: Then just a matter or correctly naming what you post back (with indexers) so that it binds to your model.

Comment: IT works only if I add `formData.append(data, "files[i]")` and in action I put `List<HttpPostedFileBase> data`, works perfectly. I don't know why is not working with custom objects ...

Comment: Have not tested, but `formData.append('[0].Description', 'abc'); formData.append('[0].File', files[0]); formData.append('[1].Description', 'def'); formData.append('[1].File', files[1]);` etc should work

Comment: Oh, my God, thanks a million. Please post your last command as answer, and I'll accept it !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order bind to a collection of complex objects, the names (in the name/value pairs) must include indexers. Your script needs to add the names to `FormData` in the following format - `'[0].Files', '[0].Description', '[1].Files', '[1].Description'` etc

```
$("#chooseFile").on("change", function() {
  var files = $(this).prop("files");
  var formData = new FormData();
  for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('[' + i + '].File', files[i]);
    formData.append('[' + i + '].Description', 'My custom description' + i);
  }
  var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ....
```

Comment: How would you append if there are multiple lists `List1, List2`, how would you identify a particular list. How about `formData.append('List1[' + i + '].File', files[i]);`?

Comment: @BilalAhmed, If you model contains a collection property named `List` where each object in the collection contains a property named `File`, then that is exactly how you would do it.